# How to get the Control with the focus in a subform?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, focus

Ms-access VBA raises an error when when me.myControl has the focus and I am trying to set

```
me.myControl.visible=false
```

So I use Screen.ActiveControl to figure out if myControl has the focus:

```
if me.myControl.name = Screen.ActiveControl.name then
    me.otherControl.SetFocus
end if
me.myControl.visible=false
```

Unfortunately it seems like every subform can have its own "ActiveControl". I did not find a way to figure out which one it is. So I have to do this workaround:

```
on error goto setMyfocus
me.subform.Form!myCtrlInSubform.visible = false
exit function

setMyfocus:
me.subform.Form!otherCtrlInSubform.SetFocus
me.subform.Form!myCtrlInSubform.visible = false
exit function
```

Obviously this is no good solution. So is there a way to figure out which control in the subform has the focus without raising an error?

Comment: Why do you say `on error` is not good? This is similar to a try...catch. You expect an error to happen, you then account for the different scenarios that would cause an error. It may seem dirty in ms access, but you are handling the exceptions that occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```vb
' It's my main form:
If Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "YourFormName" Then
  ' And it's my subform:
  If Forms!YourFormName.ActiveControl.Name = "subform" Then
    ' And it's my control in subform:
    If Screen.ActiveControl.Name = "myCtrlInSubform" Then
      Me.subform.Form!otherCtrlInSubform.SetFocus
      Me.subform.Form!myCtrlInSubform.Visible = False
    End If
  End If
End If
```